# jQuery get element by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementsbyname

I wanna transform our javascript to jQuery due to necessary reduction of characters. This is my HTML & Javascript

```js
var shorty = document.getElementsByName("DPdays")[0].getElementsByTagName("td")[i].id;
```

```html
<tr class="DPtag" name="DPdays">
 <td id="MO">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="DI">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="MI">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="DO">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="FR">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="SA">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="SO">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

I tried those:

```js
var shorty = $('.DPtag > td:eq('+i+')').attr('id');
var shorty = $('[name=DPdays] > td:eq('+i+')').attr('id');
var shorty = $('[name=DPdays] > td:eq('+i+')').id;
```

But none works. How can I do that?

Comment: `$('.DPtag > td:eq('+i+')').attr('id');` should work fine. what do `$('.DPtag > td)` returns?

Comment: First and second selector is right but third isn't. See https://jsfiddle.net/LgjoLc14/

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Actually your could should work as expected. So there is something else wrong in your code ...

Comment: $("[name='DPdays']").filter("td")[0].id; this will give id of first td.

Comment: So you add a few KB of jQuery to reduce JavaScript? ;)

Comment: TR elements do not have a `name` attribute. So start by fixing your invalid HTML. And then use either the class to select the element(s), or use an id if you need to select a more specific element.

Comment: @epascarello: jQuery is loaded with or without my code so I do reduce ;)

Comment: Nowhere in your question do you state what, precisely, the problem is that you want to solve, or what output/result you want. You show code that currently works, but reference a variable that isn't defined (in your code). Do you want the `id` of the `<td>` elements? Of all of them, or just one? As an Array, or a String?

Comment: David Thomas, a) I need to reduce characters because I have to, b) there I need the IDs of all <td>-elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you don't need jQuery to write it more concisely:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name=DPdays] td')[i].id
```

but if you prefer jQuery

```
$('[name=DPdays] td')[i].id
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that at least in Chrome and Firefox it's not possible to select the `<td>` elements if they are not included in a `<table>` tag. Which is not valid HTML anyway if you don't do that.
I assume that `i` is a variable in a loop to get all ids. In jQuery you could do it like that:

```
var $td = $('.DPtag td'); 
for (var i = 0; i < $td.length; i++) {
  var shorty = $td[i].id;
  console.log(shorty);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q3q076tn/

**EDIT:** Of course you could write it without jQuery as simple as exchanging:

`var $td = $('.DPtag td');`

with:

`var $td = document.querySelectorAll('.DPtag td');`

**Important nodes:** It's not a good idea to get the data like it's done in the question and in the accepted answer.

1. You would reselect/search all the `<td>` elements in every single
   iteration of the loop. That makes it just unnecessarily slow.
2. You use the name property for a `<tr>` tag which is not valid HTML. As already mentioned from *CBroe*. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name This is why you should select it via class or ID.

Comment: Or in a more functional way: `console.log($('.DPtag td').map(function (td) { return td.id });`